# No es posible establecer una conexión con SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql

estoy teniendo un inconveniente un poco raro. Hace 9 meses tengo un VPS Windows con base de datos SQL Server, el cual estuve usando siempre desde un WebHosting que se conectaba remotamente a mi servidor. Ayer repentinamente el VPS sufrió un reinicio forzado seguramente por algunas aplicaciones que estaban corriendo y consumian demasiada memoria, hoy cuando intento acceder a mi sitio web me encuentro con que no es posible establecer la conexión con el servidor.

El puerto está bien, los servicios están iniciados TCP/IP está habilitado, usuario y contraseña está todo OK, no puedo encontrar una respuesta al porque no se puede conectar.

Este reinicio forzado habrá dañado el SQL Server o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que reiniciaras correctamente el VPS, ya que de esa manera puedes que el inicio del sistema repare algún servicio o registro defectuoso. Comenta que tal te va.

Comment: Si lo hice, pero sigue igual!! Si le hago un Port Check remoto me dice que está abierto, como que si se está ejecutando todo ok, probe creando otro usuario y nada

Comment: En serverfault.com seguro logras una respuesta más adecuada (sólo va en inglés, eso sí)